# C# and Javascript code calculations giving different results

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I'm doing a Unity project where I have the need to convert UTM coordinates to latitudes and longitudes. I have tried several C# solutions, but none of them were accurate enough. But I found some Javascript code that gives out the exact result I'm looking for (https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-utm-mgrs.html). The problem is, when I turned the code into C#, it gives out a different result. Here are the pieces of code I see the problem in:

Javascript:

```
var a = 6378137;
var f = 1/298.257223563;
var e = Math.sqrt(f*(2-f));
var n = f / (2 - f);
var n2 = n*n, n3 = n*n2, n4 = n*n3, n5 = n*n4, n6 = n*n5;
var A = a/(1+n) * (1 + 1/4*n2 + 1/64*n4 + 1/256*n6);
```

And the C# code I converted myself:

```
var a = 6378137;
var f = 1 / 298.257223563;
var e = Math.Sqrt(f * (2 - f));
var n = f / (2 - f);
var n2 = n * n;
var n3 = n2 * n;
var n4 = n3 * n;
var n5 = n4 * n;
var n6 = n5 * n;
var A = a / (1 + n) * (1 + 1 / 4 * n2 + 1 / 64 * n4 + 1 / 256 * n6);
```

They should be identical, but the value of A is different. In `Javascript` it's `6367449.145823415` (what I want), but `C#` gives `6367444.6571225897487819833001`. I could just use the `Javascript` code in my project, but conveniently Unity stopped supporting `Javascript` just last year.

The inputs are the same for both functions. What could be the issue here?

Comment: Make sure your current culture(en-gb) is the same on client(browser) and server(c# code).

Comment: @IsmailYilmaz culture has nothing to do with mathematical calculations. All numbers are litteral here (not somehow parsed from strings)

Comment: @Pac0 Thank you for informing me about this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have an issue in the last expression

```
var A = a / (1 + n) * (1 + 1 / 4 * n2 + 1 / 64 * n4 + 1 / 256 * n6);
```

In C# `1 / 4 * n2` is evaluated to `0` since `1` and `4` are considered as integers by default and integer division `1 / 4` gives `0`. Same thing happens to `1 / 64 * n4` and `1 / 256 * n6`. But in JavaScript there are only 64-bit floating point numbers, so `1 / 4` is evaluated to `0.25`.

Possible workaround:

```
var A = a / (1 + n) * (1 + 1 / 4.0 * n2 + 1 / 64.0 * n4 + 1 / 256.0 * n6);
```

Now answers seem to be exactly the same.

Note: as @Lithium mentioned, you may find more elegant to add `d` rather than `.0` to the end of the number to indicate it as `double`.

Comment: Now this looks like a sensible answer, with actual tests

Comment: Behold the integer division !

Comment: Beside adding the `.0` to the end of a number you can also postpend a `d`. Like `4d` this will tell the compiler that it is a double.

Comment: Also, adding an `f` will result in a `float` and `m` will give `decimal` for when precision really is required.

Comment: @Lithium, yes, it make sense; I have edited the answer

Comment: How about instead of using 1/4.0 or 1/4d just to use 0.25

Comment: @DanielP I think in this particular case it will be more readable to use fractions (especially for 1/256)

Comment: Saved my day - Adding F after the hard-codded number (converted it to single) and the result was the same in JS. Thank You!

Answer (score -2):

In your C# use all your variables as type `double`. These are twice as accurate as the standard C# floats which I assume it is using by default.

This should give you an identical answer.

Most languages have the concept of a single precision floating point number and a double precision floating point number (32 bit vs 64 bit). Due to JavaScript being a Non-strongly typed language I'm assuming it's picking up the fact that it should use 64 bits for your numbers whereas C# needs to be told that. You should also avoid var in C# wherever possible and use the actual type, to avoid situations like this :p

Comment: As far as I have checked, these `var`s are already being resolved as `double`s.

Comment: All the vars resolve to double, except `a` resolves to be an int

Comment: @Lithium No. It's still a double

Comment: It still seems like a precision issue so I'm unsure. Potentially see if you can check how your C# is set up to handle precision (truncation vs rounding). hat's the only other thing I can think of. And as said above, a being a double may cause an issue so make sure it's created as an int

Comment: @Programmer `var a` resolves to an int. `var A` is a double

Comment: @Lithium Sorry. I thought you meant A. confused the A and a.

Comment: It should be noted that JavaScript does not have distinct number types, there is only one number type. Numbers are all double precision floating point numbers (64-bit) in javascript.

Answer (score -2):

This likely has to do with the lack of handling for floating point numbers in javascript. C# handles it fine but not Javascript. If you would like to know more about some of the quirks in Javascript numbers check out the link below.

[https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp](http://%20https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_numbers.asp)

Comment: It's actually the other way round C# is handling 1/4, 1/64 and 1/256 as integer division and are all evaluated as 0 (zero)